# How to find the cause of "Uncaught PHP Exception"

Tags: debugging, 9

When I go to any page, the following error appears in the log:

```
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 20333] [client 172.18.0.6:52608] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message:
 Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\MethodNotAllowedException:
 "" at /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/MethodFilter.php line 46', referer: 
 http://example.dk.ddev.site/da
```

At first I thought it had something to do with my new theme that I am about to make. But if I change theme, the error is still there. I am using Drupal v9.2.5.

How do I track down the cause of the error?

Comment: It's a `MethodNotAllowedException`. I'd guess it refers to the request method, `GET`, `POST` etc, and that the route in question only allows certain request methods, and the user has accessed the route with an unallowed method.

Comment: Is /da a custom route? Start there.